# Does YouTube allow multiple soundtracks

Tags: youtube

Is it possible to upload one video on YouTube, and have multiple soundtracks for it? Much like one can choose the subtitles, can one make several language-specific voice-overs for the same, say, screen-cast?

If that feature is not present on YouTube, are there calls or plans for it? What other services may have this implemented?

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @pnz Yes. Read [this article](https://newzhook.com/story/assassin-creed-video-gaming-ubisoft-outube-now-has-ability-to-add-multiple-audio-tracks-including-audio-description-for-blind-viewers/). Assassin's Creed Valhalla trailer uses this feature.

Answer (score 7):

When uploading to YouTube: no (for now...)
Your audio needs to be premixed into one stereo (or mono) channel.

When using YouTube's online video editor: yes, but you are limited to voice-over and music tracks

For more info:
http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183851
(see point 4. adding audio)

Comment: Talking about online editor, not really a “yes”, is it? While one can add voice-over before publishing, it does not allow for the two different sound tracks to be chosen from for the same video.

Comment: Hence, my "limited" remark

Comment: That's still not giving the viewer a choice of audio track.

Comment: just a test comment to follow post

Answer (score 4):

As of now, Youtube doesn't allow multiple soundtracks other than adding a music-track.  So you'll need to create multiple videos with voice-over for different languages. Thankfully however this is already automated using a bash script.

[Demo Video with Automatic voice-over translation from SRT subtitles using eSpeak](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ud38LEKKY6k)
[VoiceOver Script Version 0.3 to convert Subtitle file to Audio Track using eSpeak](http://www.particio.com/downloads/voiceover-0.3)

This solution works on Linux but I guess one can use Ubuntu Linux as a VM using virtualbox on windows.

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm guessing the API has changed.

Answer (score -2):

here watch this video, here in settings there are different languages in which you may select of your choice.

Comment: While this does indicate the answer (which is yes) it doesn't really provide any useful info to the OP, unlike the other answers. Sadly they may well be outdated now.

Comment: What are you talking about? What settings? There are no language settings for videos other than subtitles.

Comment: Indeed, the answer is actually "no".

Comment: Apparently incorrect answers should not be removed...